# How do I correctly post form data to a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to post data from a form to a controller action. I've created the form with HTML.BeginForm() and I have a controller which works fine when I manually create the query string, but I don't understand how to make a form work with my controller action.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneralSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @Html.TextBox("searchString")

                            <button type="submit" class="default">Submit</button>
                        }

                    </div>
                </form>
```

And then in my controller I currently have the `HttpGet` attribute that ASP.NET automatically placed there. However, if I change it to `HttpPost` the problem still occurs.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GeneralSearch(string searchString)
    {
        return View("SearchResult", viewModel);
    }
```

When I enter text and submit the form, a network request is sent to:

`http://localhost:64562/?searchString=test`

Which simply loads the default controller and action instead of the "Search" controller I specified in the `using` statement. How do I correctly post to a specific action?

Comment: Look at the rendered html for the form. You'll need an input with `name="searchString"` for the binding to work. Also, the form action is Post but your action is marked `[HttpGet]`. GET parameters are passed through the query string and POST parameters passed in the request body.

Comment: Isn't the name given in the Textbox method the name used in the HTML?

Comment: @user9993 - It would probably be best for you to complete an online tutorial or do some reading. Something like [Getting Data From View to Controller in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-data-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc/). The alternative is to painstakingly stumble through it error by error.

Answer (score 3):

`Html.BeginForm(` adds a `<Form>` tag but I see you are trying to add the form tag inside another form tag as seen below; which is wrong.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneralSearch", "Search",
```

Again, your controller must expose different action method to cater `GET` and `POST` request and you should rather have

```
public ActionResult GeneralSearch()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneralSearch(string searchString)
{
    return View("SearchResult", viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are POSTing to a method that is listening to GET.

Switch the FormMethod

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneralSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
```

Comment: You should probably add something about the existing `HttpGet` as well on the controller action.